# asp.net MVC 3 pagination which is best to use

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

At this point with MVC 3 , what is the best way to use pagination with going through a fixed number of records with data?  I prefer to stay away from jgrid and those types of heavy javascript grids... but with all the flavors of html helpers, is there any at this point that really stands out as superior?  ( I need to have tabs that each reflect data grid that can be sorted and most importantly have the previous and next buttons )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a subjective question so here's my subjective answer: personally I like and use [MVCContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&ProjectName=mvccontrib) and had also great experience with the [Telerik MVC Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) as well and may recommend it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured mvccontrib grid would come up, I just wish there was a standard without the whole 3rd party component thing.  Like how GridView is built into web forms, such someone can go use 10 differents COTS apps like Telerik, componentone, dexexpress , infragristics and the list seems to never end.

Comment: @Tom Stickel, the only thing that is built into ASP.NET MVC 3 is the WebGrid control but it sucks so badly that in real world applications it's totally useless. Maybe in future versions of ASP.NET MVC Microsoft will provide their own implementation. But today that's how things are.

Answer (score 2):

[Flexgrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/) is a pretty solid client side grid that supports pagination, column sorting, searching, etc. It's really quite lightweight as well, and supports both json and xml data formats.

Comment: That is an interesting grid.  I need to check it out.  Thanks.